# How do I use PuTTY with X forwarding when opened by WinSCP?

Tags: ssh, putty, winscp, xforwarding

How do I setup up PuTTY to use X forwarding when opened by WinSCP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Winscp: `Options -> Preferences -> Integration -> Applications` add `-X` parameter to putty.exe path

More parameters [here](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#3.7)

Link to [WinSCP documentation](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_integration_app) on configuring PuTTY command-line:

Comment: May need to add parameter outside of quotes:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe" -X